# JS Cookie doesnot available in server side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

This is how I create my cookie with Javascript and after that redirect to cart page.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var expires = ";expires=" + d.toUTCString();
var product = { productId: btn.value, colorId: productColorId, quantity: 0 };
products.push(product);
document.cookie = "products=" + JSON.stringify(products) + expires + "; path=/; SameSite=strict";
window.location.href = "cart";
```

and I can find this cookie in my browser in cookie section, but in server side I get nothing.

At first I use this code and I get null.

```
string products = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["products"];
```

After that I try this code

```
if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("products", out cookieValue))
{
   // TODO: use the cookieValue
}
else
{
   // this cookie doesn't exist.
}
```

and always it runs else, It seems, even don't find cookie.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Are you actually sending the cookie in any of your requests?

Comment: @AhmedBajra How to send it? before it I always create my cookies in server side.

Comment: Depending on the requests you're sending from client side, you may want to use [cookie headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie)

Comment: Are your server and your client using the same domain?

Comment: @Nico yes domain of both them is localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives),a  can optionally be set in double quotes and any US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs, whitespace, double quotes, comma, semicolon, and backslash are allowed.

Try the following changes in your javascript ,use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to convert double quotes

```
document.cookie = "products=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(product)) + expires + "; path=/; SameSite=strict";
```

The screenshot of the cookie value got in the server-side
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have been banging my head on this problem for hours.

Answer (score 0):

In response to a comment, Cookie headers in javascript is forbidden, which means it cannot be set programmatically. Only the browser may set it, and it may choose to not send cookie information along with the HTTP request depending on their browser settings. (Typically inside privacy settings)

First I would confirm that the cookie header is indeed being sent. You can usually find this out by using the browser's web inspector and looking at network request. Here is a screenshot in chrome:

[image: Google Chrome Network tab]

If you **don't** see the cookie header then I would advise double checking browser privacy settings to ensure cookies are enabled and disabling ad/tracking blockers if you have them installed. If this is a case, unfortunately there isn't much you can do other than beg the user to change their settings or disable their ad blockers.

If you **DO** see the cookie header, then this suggest that it may be a problem in the back-end code, but I'm not familiar with ASP.NET so I can't really comment on that.

Hope this helps